# Cannot cast object '{}' with class 'groovy.util.ConfigObject' to class 'java.lang.Integer' exception when downgrading to grails 2.1.0

Tags: grails, type-conversion, constants

I was using grails 2.1.1 and I moved back to 2.1.0. After this move I had problem with accessing constants I put inside bootstrap file using grailsApplication . for example  when running the following code:

```
def list(Integer max) {
        max=max ?: grailsApplication.config.LIST_MAX
}
```

I got this exception:

```
org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.GroovyCastException: Cannot cast object '{}' with class 'groovy.util.ConfigObject' to class 'java.lang.Integer'
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.DefaultTypeTransformation.castToNumber(DefaultTypeTransformation.java:146)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.DefaultTypeTransformation.castToType(DefaultTypeTransformation.java:248)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.castToType(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:599)
    at accountcontrol.AuditController.list(AuditController.groovy:16)
    at accountcontrol.AuditController.list(AuditController.groovy)
    at accountcontrol.AuditController$list.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:42)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:112)
    at accountcontrol.AuditControllerTests.testList(AuditControllerTests.groovy:32)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:45)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:42)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:30)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:263)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:68)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:47)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:231)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:60)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:222)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:30)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:300)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

Any idea how to solve it?

Thanks,

Comment: From the stack trace it looks like this is in a unit test, so can you share the code of the test class as well as the controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this way?

```
def list(Integer max) {
        max=max?.toString().isNumber()?max:grailsApplication.config.LIST_MAX
}
```

Comment: the problem is that grailsApplication.config.LIST_MAX doesn't return integer. It returns config Object.

Comment: and seems that it returns Object just because grailsApplication.config.LIST_MAX is empty

Comment: Why it is empty? I'm sure it is defined on bootstrap file.

Comment: If it returns config object is empty. Pleate attache the code of the bootstrap where you define it